# View Pager 2 /Recycler view crash for inconsistency

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, crash, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

Getting this crash in my app . Think it's some issue with viewpager2 but couldn't come to conclusion. Tried notifyDatasetchanged() but isnt working with it.

```
Process: PID: 19449
      **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:**

     **Inconsistency detected.**


     **Invalid item position 0(offset:-1).state:5 
     androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2$RecyclerViewImpl{ee4a46e VFED..... ......ID 0,0-1080,1776 
     #7},
     adapter:abc.adapter.ABCPagerAdapter@c87b70f,
     layout:androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2$LinearLayoutManagerImpl@429b39c,
     context:abc.view.ABCActivity**


    @f6d7d59 at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
            at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onLayout(ViewPager2.java)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:)
            at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.onLayout(NestedScrollView.java)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:
```

This Exception came when you try to do something like this:

(A) Add an element in Arraylist or List if List/ArrayList is Full.

(B) When you try to delete an item from empty List/ArrayList

It's good if you simplify your question by mentioning in which action you are getting this error or which class

Comment: That's what the issue is this is the exact log. Not able to find the exact class for it.

Comment: Share your Adapter class and Activity which invoke adapter